# Animate from none to block, javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, block

Here's my script...how can I get the divs that are being displayed on click (block) to slide down instead of just appear instantly? I've seen this asked and answered but all the answers are in jquery and I can't even begin to understand how to add it. I don't know any jquery and I barely understand javascript. I got this bit of code from a template for click show/hide functionality.

```
function HideContent(d) {
document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
}
function ShowContent(d) {
document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block"; 
}
function ReverseDisplay(d) {
if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none") { document.getElementById(d).style.display=    "block"; }
else { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; }
}
```

Comment: Instead of Javascript animations, you should use jQuery's [`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function in the [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event you are binding to the `div`. And then, in your CSS, you can use [transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) for the classes for the slidedown effect you are looking for. Keywords in this comment are links btw.

Comment: Yes I know, I've seen that answer all over the place. But how? What do I change in my script?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the effect of animation, elements must be moved at a given interval or frame rate. The simplest way to do this is to set up an animation loop with a delay.
So use `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, which when called as `setTimeout(c,t)` and `setInterval(c,t)` allow for execution of javascript code c at t miliseconds from now in the case of setTimeout, and every t miliseoncds in the case of setInterval.

```
setTimeout(doSomething,500); // calls doSomething() 500 miliseconds from now
setInterval(doSomething,500); // calls doSomething() every 500 miliseconds until stopped
```

An example of this can be found [here](http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-1/)
You will pretty much have to write all the code yourself. there is an complicated [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/LzX4s/) that does this but the level involved is high.

But to be honest thats not the easiest way to do it. [jQuery](http://jQuery.com) is a great resource, a javascript library that can do many things like [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). It would stand to you to look for a simple jQuery tutorial and then go from there. There are plenty of them online.

**jQuery Example**
[Heres a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/cX88R/) with code example of how to fade in and out.

Comment: Oh wow...thank you for the fast response. I thought there would be a much simpler answer, but I guess I'll look for some jQuery tutorials.

Comment: No problem - the simplest you can get without the slide functionality....http://jsfiddle.net/cX88R/235/

Comment: You can find other animation examples here at the bottom of the page http://api.jquery.com/animate/